# Create iOS Project using shellscript

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, cordova, xcode6

I am working on some custom ios project template, I tried to create a template using xcode template but because of the limitation of xcode wizard not able to further. So i am looking for some alternative way to create iOS project. How does cross platform like PhoneGap creating Xcode project on command line ?
Is there any way we can create an xcode project using shell script  ? please help me ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
cordova platform add ios
```

done

to verify, go to `your_project_name` > `platform` > `ios` > `your_project_name.xcodeproj`

Comment: Thanks Nurdin, But this is not what i am looking for. I want to know how cordova creating the ios project. Script behind the cordova platform add ios action..